# How to get object name from variable pointing to it in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I'm trying to figure out whether it is possible to get object name out of variable that is just pointing to it.
So lets say I have code like this:

```
var myObj = {
   content: "this is my object"
}

var pointer = myObj;
// any way to get "myObj" string from "pointer" variable?

var myFunc = function(parameter) {
   console.log(parameter)
   // any way to get "myObj" string from "parameter" variable inside function?
}
myFunc(myObj)
```

Any way to get original object name in Javascript as string rather than object itself?

Can it be done some other way if above methods cannot be used?

Comment: In the current version of javascript I do not think it is possible.

Comment: `parameter.content` and `pointer.content`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myObj` is not the original object name, but rather the name of the variable that holds a reference to your object. From that perspective, it is really no different than `pointer`.

To my knowledge, it is currently not possible to get the names of the variables holding a reference to an object from the object alone.

Answer (score -3):

Hope it will help.

```
var myObj = {
   content: "this is my object"
   name : 'myobj'
}

var pointer = myObj;
// any way to get "myObj" string from "pointer" variable?
//string variable.
name = pointer.name;

var myFunc = function(parameter) {
   console.log(parameter.name)
   // any way to get "myObj" string from "parameter" variable inside function?
}
myFunc(myObj)
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Creating a JavaScript Object.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue",name:"Person"};

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
person.firstName + " is " + person.age + " years old." +person.name;
</script>

</body>
</html>

It is working then why did you down vote?

Comment: I mean, sure it works, so does `var x = 1 + 1`, but the code is not doing what was asked.

Comment: You have asked is it possible. And i have just show you a way to do that.

Comment: well, no, your code stores the name of the variable somewhere else, and you get it from that rather than from the value, which is what was being asked.

Comment: that's indeed workaround I was thinking about and which I have as a plan B, but was hoping for some more neat solution

Answer (score -3):

From what I understand you want to get the object name which is passed thru as a parameter, not the object value.

If so in myFunc do:

```
for (n in parameter) { console.log(n); }
```